# Echo results based on date UNIX_TIMESTAMP

Tags: php

I'm trying to build a `statement view` for my site so my users can view their income and out goings for the `14 day period` basically what I'm having trouble with is echoing out the transactions for a 14 day period. every 14 days a new statement is generated how do I select all the entry's from a table from a specific date? for example  `01/01/2016` to `14/01/2016`. is there a specific script I can use to do this?

I'm going to upload the structure of my table to help you better understand what I'm asking.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Below is an SQL query based on your above table, this should select all transactions between the two required dates.

```
SELECT * FROM `tansactions`
WHERE `timestamp` >= UNIX_TIMESTAMP('2016-01-01 00:00:00')
AND `timestamp` <= UNIX_TIMESTAMP('2016-01-14 23:59:50');
```

Comment: your amazing dudeee thank you I really appreciate it; will mark this the answer

Comment: @LewisTyler Not a problem!